# Unity - Access g buffer in shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to read from the g-buffer in Unity using deferred shading path in my shader. This works great if my material is rendered in the overlay queue, or as an image effect attached to a camera. It does not work if I am rendering in the Geometry or Background queue, the g-buffer is black in these cases. Why is that? I would have thought the g-buffer would accumulate for each material and could be read by any subsequent material. I may not fully understand the deferred pipeline clearly.